# How to preserve whitespace?

Tags: html

I have a text box that when I paste code into it removes the white space . This is a problem is it is much more difficult to read the code. How can I modify the text box to preserve whitespace formatting?

Comment: Could you maybe expand your question? Maybe with code you've tried or images/examples of what goes wrong?

Comment: JSFiddle/codepen link maybe?

Answer (score 3):

CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```html
<TEXTAREA style="white-space: pre">Hello,  world</TEXTAREA>
```

Other options for `white-space`:

- **normal**: Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary. This is default
- **nowrap**:Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
   tag is encountered
- **pre**: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the  tag in HTML
- **pre-line**: Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
- **pre-wrap**: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
- **initial**:Sets this property to its default value.
- **inherit**:  Inherits this property from its parent element.